# Nuxt generate blank pages if using v-for

Tags: nuxt.js, v-for

My nuxt app works fine when in dev, but once I generate static pages, the ones that contains a v-for= are completely white, even if there's some code in the page on generate.
Is this a bug?

Here's the page content:

```html
<template>
  <section class="page">
    <figure v-for="n in 4">
      <picture>
        <source :srcset="require('~/data/' + detail.id + '-' + n + '.jpg?webp')" type="image/webp" />
        <source :srcset="require('~/data/' + detail.id + '-' + n + '.jpg')" type="image/jpeg" />
        <img :src="require('~/data/' + detail.id + '-' + n + '.jpg')" />
      </picture>
    </figure>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import details from '~/data/details.json'

export default {
  asyncData ({ params }) {
    return { details }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    detail () {
      return this.details.find(detail => detail.id === this.id)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and the .json

```js
[
  {
    "id": "screen-one"
  },
  {
    "id": "screen-two"
  },
  {
    "id": "screen-three"
  }
]
```

and then. as I incurred immediately in this problem, I was manually adding the urls in nuxt.config.js

```js
  generate: {
    routes: [
      '/screen-one',
      '/screen-two',
      '/screen-three'
    ]
  },
```

The images (like screen-one-1.jpg) are in the data folder.

The page is named _id.vue

Comment: Include some of the code in question so that we can help.  There are lots of reasons this may be happening.

Comment: I'm guessing your use of `require` in the `srcset` binding is causing the issue. Have you tried replacing it with back-ticks (i.e. `:srcset="\`~/data/${detail.id}-${n}.jpg?webp\`"`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was related to '?webp', related to the dependency "@bazzite/nuxt-optimized-images". I can't remember what was the issue, but has nothing to do with v-for or nuxt itself. Thanks!